# Python convert Pandas to nested JSON

Tags: json, python-3.x, pandas

I am looping through the records in the dataframe and need to convert each row to separate nested JSON

```
from pprint import pprint
pprint(pd.to_dict())
```

```
{'id':{0: 'A'},
'col1':{0: 'B'},
'address_id':{0: ['123','ABC']},
'address_1':{0: ['Street 123','Street ABC']},
'address_2':{0: ['Road 123','Road ABC']},
'city':{0: ['Dallas','Houston']},
'state':{0: ['Texas','Texas']},
'addition_details':{0: ['XYZ','LMP']},
}
```

The expected JSON format for reach record is below, I need help to convert to desired output:

```
{
  'id': 'A',
  'col1': 'B',
  'address': [{
      'address_id': '123',
      'address_1': 'Street 123',
      'address_2': 'Road 123',
      'city': 'Dallas',
      'state': 'Texas'
    },
    {
      'address_id': 'ABC',
      'address_1': 'Street ABC',
      'address_2': 'Road ABC',
      'city': 'Houston',
      'state': 'Texas'
    }
  ],
  'criteria': [{
      'addition_details': 'XYZ'
    },
    {
      'addition_details': 'LMP'
    },
  ]
}
```

I tried to combine address field:

```
json_output=(pd.groupby(['id','col1'])
              .apply(lambda x: x[['address_id','address_1','address_2','city','state']].to_dist('list'))
              .reset_index(name='address').to_json(orient='records'))
print(json.dumps(json.loads(json_output),index=2, sort_keys=True))
```

I am not getting the desired output:

```
[
{
"id":"A",
"col1":"B",
"address":{
  "address_id":[
[
  '123',
  'ABC'
]],
"address_1":[
[
  'Street 123',
  'Street ABC'
]],
"address_2":[
[
  'Road 123',
  'Road ABC'
]],
....
```

Comment: *Side note*: Customarily, users [`import pandas as pd`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/10min.html) and don't use `pd` as a variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this is the cleanest approach, but if you need a quick fix this rather manual approach works:

```py
# Set up the sample DataFrame
data = {'id': {0: 'A'},
        'col1': {0: 'B'},
        'address_id': {0: ['123', 'ABC']},
        'address_1': {0: ['Street 123', 'Street ABC']},
        'address_2': {0: ['Road 123', 'Road ABC']},
        'city': {0: ['Dallas', 'Houston']},
        'state': {0: ['Texas', 'Texas']},
        'addition_details': {0: ['XYZ', 'LMP']}}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Next we manually handle the conversion

```py
# Setup a dictionary and populate it with the easy values.
result = {'id': df.at[0, 'id'],
          'col1': df.at[0, 'col1'],
          'address': [],
          'criteria': []}

# Obtain the address entry:
for i in range(len(df.at[0, 'address_id'])):
    address_entry = {
        'address_id': df.at[0, 'address_id'][i],
        'address_1': df.at[0, 'address_1'][i],
        'address_2': df.at[0, 'address_2'][i],
        'city': df.at[0, 'city'][i],
        'state': df.at[0, 'state'][i]
    }
    result['address'].append(address_entry)


# Obtain the criteria entry:
for i in range(len(df.at[0, 'addition_details'])):
    criteria_entry = {
        'addition_details': df.at[0, 'addition_details'][i]
    }
    result['criteria'].append(criteria_entry)

# Convert the result to JSON
json_output = json.dumps(result, indent=2)
print(json_output)
```

Related to your question is your original DataFrame's structuring. Your DataFrame structure (having more than one entry per column, but only one row) is unusual and generally not recommended. Depending on the purpose of this code, and the goals for long term maintainability, you might want to rethink this structure.
With a more standard structured DataFrame it's often easier to convert it to other formats too.

Comment: thanks this works for me. Will check on the maintainability aspect. Appreciate your time.